# Docker "write only" volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions

I would like to have a Docker container be able to copy files into a volume without being able to read its contents / know what files are inside of it.

The container should also be able to append contents to a file inside that volume.

Is there a way to achieve any of this by using Docker compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Docker volumes are mounted to the filesystem either read-write or read-only: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume.

Comment: if there was a write-only option it would make the node_modules issue a lot easier: https://jaygould.co.uk/2022-08-12-docker-node-problems-development-prisma/